# Defining a factorial procedure in Charme

Tags: python, scheme

I need help defining a factorial procedure in Charme. The procedure needs to be expressed as a string in Python by defining a variable called charmeFactorialDefinition. When you evaluate evalInGlobal(charmeFactorialDefinition), it should define a Charme procedure called factorial.

Output should look like this:

> > > initializeGlobalEnvironment()
> > >
> > > evalInGlobal(charmeFactorialDefinition)
> > >
> > > evalInGlobal("(factorial 5)")
> > >
> > > 120

Okay so far I know that Charme doesn't support the define shortcut for quickly listing functions and their arguments so I have to  write the answer out longhand with lambda such as:

charmeDoubleDefinition = "(define double (lambda (x) (+ x x)))"

But beyond that, I have no clue how to start

Comment: What is "Charme"?  It looks like a Python library for some sort of LISP/Scheme dialect or something.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a link to [charme](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs1120-f09/ps/ps7/) for people who don't know what you are talking about. Though this might solve your problem.

```
charmeFactorialDefinition = "(define factorial (lambda (x) (if (> x 1) (* x factorial(x)) (1) ) ))"
```